# undefined reference to class::() C++

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

I'm just learning constructor and destructor I'm following the tutorial this guy is doing [bucky tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=134&v=4P4Im0vF_mU). I think the video is outdated? since I followed every single step he says and i'm still getting an error.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TESTING.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    TESTING so;
    cout << "TEST" << endl;

}
```

**TESTING.h**

```
#ifndef TESTING_H
#define TESTING_H


class TESTING
{
    public:
        TESTING();
    protected:
        private:
};

#endif // TESTING_H
```

**TESTING.cpp**

```
#include "TESTING.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


TESTING::TESTING()
{
    cout << "TESTTTTT!!" << endl;
}
```

**Error messages**

\main.o:main.cpp undefined reference to 'TESTING::TESTING()'

**Build log**

```
mingw32-g++.exe   -c D:\C++\TESTING!\main.cpp -o D:\C++\TESTING!\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe  -o D:\C++\TESTING!\main.exe D:\C++\TESTING!\main.o   
D:\C++\TESTING!\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `TESTING::TESTING()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

You only build and link the `main` source file, not the `TESTING` source file. You need to compile `TESTING.cpp` as well, and then link with `TESTING.o`:

```
mingw32-g++.exe   -c D:\C++\TESTING!\TESTING.cpp -o D:\C++\TESTING!\TESTING.o
mingw32-g++.exe  -o D:\C++\TESTING!\main.exe D:\C++\TESTING!\main.o D:\C++\TESTING!\TESTING.o
```

Comment: How will i do that? I'm not used to this stuff yet.

Comment: @JEEZSUSCRIZE Do like show in my answer?

Comment: I compiled the TESTING.cpp and i got an error undefined reference to WinMain@16

Comment: @JEEZSUSCRIZE Then it seems that MinGW tries to create a Windows GUI-type program. I don't know MinGW well enough, but it seems you need to add a flag to tell it to build a console program, you need to read the documentation.

Comment: ok thanks i just search it

Answer (score 1):

You need to include both the compilation units in the build.

That means both source files need to be compiled, and both corresponding object files specified in the link command.

At present, only main.cpp is being compiled to an object, and only main.o is being linked.